# Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context?

Tags: php

i'm getting this error and i dont know what to do?

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in
> /home/lumato/domains/lumato.nglyceum.eu/public_html/DBController.php:18
> Stack trace: #0
> /home/lumato/domains/lumato.nglyceum.eu/public_html/drinks.php(144):
> runQuery('SELECT * FROM P...') #1 {main} thrown in
> /home/lumato/domains/lumato.nglyceum.eu/public_html/DBController.php
> on line 18

```
<?php
function __construct() {
    $this->conn = $this->connectDB();
}

function connectDB() {
    $conn = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password,$this->database);
    return $conn;
}

function runQuery($query) {
    $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $resultset[] = $row;
    }       
    if(!empty($resultset))
        return $resultset;
}

function numRows($query) {
    $result  = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
    $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    return $rowcount;   
}
```

?>

Comment: You have class methods here but not within a class - the `__construct` method is used to instantiate a class where `$this` refers to the class or self.

Comment: You might want to take a tutorial about classes

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about Class in PHP.I modified your code for an example

```php
class MyQuery{
    function __construct() {
        $this->conn = $this->connectDB();
    }
    
    function connectDB() {
        $conn = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password,$this->database);
        return $conn;
    }
    
    function runQuery($query) {
        $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
        $resultset = [];
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $resultset[] = $row;
        }       
        if(!empty($resultset))
            return $resultset;
    }
    
    function numRows($query) {
        $result  = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
        $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        return $rowcount;   
    }
}

$myQuery = new MyQuery();
$myQuery->runQuery("select * from ....");
```

here is [php class document](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)